# easy IDE to get autocomplete and syntax highlighting?

Tags: windows, ide

What is a very simple to hack up IDE to get automplete/intellisense for my own language and syntax highlighting? The output will be for .NET and maybe in C++

Comment: The answer I gave below doesn't asses one issue though, why do you want to do all that work when Visual Studio already does it?

Comment: Getting visual studio to do autocomplete in a custom language seems difficult. So i am trying to find an easier solution

Answer (score 2):

[Scite](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) would probably be the best options for doing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

try [Geany](http://www.geany.org)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.e-texteditor.com/ making new language bundles for e (and Textmate, which e is based on and the bundles are compatible with both) is fairly simple and extremely well documented.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear about the "my own language" and "output will be .Net and maybe in C++".  The own language part there are many editors like [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) and the like.  When you add .Net it make me think you want to use [Visual Studio Shell](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8E5AA7B6-8436-43F0-B778-00C3BCA733D3) to make your own IDE.

That said, some editors do give you "<kbd>F5</kbd>" build experience by calling into the command line build engine.

Hope this helps.